# Protecting users with browser extension. Is it possible, if the machine is already infected?

Tags: malware, chrome, browser-extensions, browser-hijacking, trojan

Assume a trojan acquired admin privilege on a Windows 7 machine.
How easy is it for the trojan to replace/hijack/modify a browser extension without user knowing it? Is it possible?

I am thinking of implementing a chrome extension to provide additional security layer. So I would like to know whether the trojan can modify the behaviour of my "security extension" that easily. I can understand that the trojan might be able to easily uninstall the chrome extension without user knowing it (uninstalling is not a problem, but hijacking/modifying is).

Also, are there any special security mechanism to prevent the tampering of a chrome extension?

Answer (score 2):

If a process (or a user, for that matter) acquires administrative privilege on a machine, **it is able to do anything**. Included replacing a browser extension with a malware browser extension without the user knowing it.

Any security mechanism implemented inside the machine can be nullified by the malware. For instance, your homemade extension could verify its checksum to ensure it has not been tampered with; however, it would be trivial to include in the tampering code a check to falsely pass the checksum test.

Comment: I would argue that is still very unlikely that you'd have an malware aware of browser extension's less yet modify them actively

Comment: @Freedo I agree. Malware do other things than fiddling with browser extensions. However, this was OP's question.